# Replace one field with another in a method

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm trying to dynamically replace in a method body a field reference by another field reference. is that possible with bytebuddy?

The class I like to transform is like this:

```
public class TestReplace {
    @replace
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    public int printA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int printB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

The transformation consists in replacing the variables marked with @replace in the methods that visit them. The replacement will be done by variables that I will insert.

The class already transformed should look like this:

```
public class TestReplace {
    @replace
    int a = 1;
    int ___a = a * 10; // var inserted
    int b = 2;

    public int printA() {
        return ___a;
    }

    public int printB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

I am new to the subject and would appreciate any help you could give me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you need this for ?

Comment: I want to use aspect oriented programming to encrypt and decrypt a certain text field in a transparent way to the user. My idea is to decrypt the fields that contain a specific annotation and save the plain text in fields created for that purpose by an agent. Then references in the methods of the class should be changed to these new fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using `MemberSubstitution`:

```
MemberSubstitution.relaxed()
  .field(ElementMatchers.named("a"))
  .onRead()
  .doReplaceWith(otherField)
```

You can, for example, apply this transformation from a Java agent that you define using the `AgentBuilder` API. You probably also need to define the alternative field from this agent. You can reference this field using a `FieldDescription.Latent`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Rafael. It's just what I was looking for. Congratulations on the framework.